# Godox X Pro Flash Trigger Using Center Pin only does not fire Godox TT600 flash

Tags: hotshoe-flash, wireless-triggers, adapter, godox

Godox Xpro (C) mounted on Canon 5D Mark III hotshoe with single pin adapter between hotshoe and trigger will not fire Godox TT600 speedlites.  Without the adapter between hotshoe and trigger I can fire the flash every time.  Both are set in MANUAL.

Comment: Why are you using a single pin adaptor between the camera and trigger? What are the flash settings in the camera menu set to?

Comment: Um, what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

The Godox Xpro does not have a single pin trigger mode.

The Xpro can be fired from the Sync socket when configured  appropriately to provide backward compatibility.

The X1T has a single pin mode.

Also the T600 and T660 flashes can be used as single pin controllers.

Comment: The X-pro doesn't have single pin mode because it doesn't have a hotshoe. Single pin mode on the X1/X2's has nothing to do with the input signal to the trigger; it only puts the passthrough hotshoe into single pin mode. And if you block communication to/with the trigger by taping over the other pins they will still trigger a flash.

Comment: @StevenKersting, that's incorrect. First off, the X2T has no single-pin mode; only the X1T does, and it's for the sync pin on the foot to be used on non-supported systems. From the X1T-F user manual: "It is advisable to set the transmitter to single contact mode when using it to trigger the flash by PC cord or **through camera's single contact**."

Comment: @inkista, I don't have the X2T; but I do have the X1T [N], and I have experimented with it extensively trying to get it to trigger my AD200's in tail sync. Based on the manual center pin mode should work, but it doesn't; it still communicates with the camera/flash and switches the flash into HSS. You can prevent that by taping over the TTL/communication contacts and forcing single pin/dumb mode; but then it loses offset sync timing. The only way tail sync is really possible is to turn off the AD200's internal receiver and use an XTR-16 on it instead...

Comment: Everyone, thanks for the input.

Comment: @StevenKersting ...or you cable an X1R or R2 SPT receiver to the AD200. Godox tail-sync has always required a manual-only external add-on receiver unit and cannot be done with the built-in receiver. And yes, the X1T still does full TTL/HSS radio communication; it just doesn't care what the flash hotshoe is telling it, aside from the single pin. If you had HSS set directly on the X1T that's why it's sending HSS signaling, it wasn't picking that up from the camera hotshoe via the non-sync pins.

Comment: @inkista, the X1T switches the strobe in/out of HSS based on the camera's SS (auto FP). There is no way to prevent it and no sync/HSS button/function like other triggers have. And the trigger does not get SS from the center pin; which is why taping off the other pins *does* prevent the HSS switchover, but that also prevents HSS sync timing.